# I want to figure out what should "A" is in the code below

Tags: swift

I have a class ​`Zoo`​ with a property ​`weeklyHot`​ which means the most popular one in the zoo this week. The codes below can’t work correctly, what should should be the data type of the A in order to solve the problem?

```
class Animal{

    let animal :String

    enum Gender{

        case male
        case female
        case undefined
    }

    init(animal : String) {
        self.animal = animal
    }

    func eat(){
        print("I eat everyyhing")
    }
}

class Elephant : Animal{

    override func eat() {
        print("I eat grass")
    }
}

class Tiger : Animal{

    override func eat() {
        print("I eat meat")
    }
}

class Horse : Animal{

    override func eat() {
        print("I eat grass, too")
    }
}

class Zoo {

    var weekHot : A
    init(weeklyHot : A ){}
}

let zoo = Zoo(weeklyHot:Tiger())
zoo.weeklyHot = tiger
```

[image]

Comment: Where is A? Code is unclear on this.

Comment: Sorry~  the code is correct now

Comment: A is class object to pass while initialization of Zoo object. This can be any class object as defined from above classes.. in the example  Tiger class object is created and passed to Zoo object while initialization.

Comment: But the code isn't work. how to fix it if I fill up the Tiger

Comment: You may try using Class Animal instead of 'A' in Zoo class. So initialization of Zoo will allow it's derived class Tiger.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to define a Zoo class which holds a variable which indicates an animal of any of the three types you defined (Elephant, Tiger or Horse) that is "hot" in the week. Since `weekHot` can be any animal, its type should be `Animal`.

In the last two lines, you are trying to declare a zoo variable whose "weekly hot" is a tiger. This can be done by `let zoo = Zoo(weeklyHot:Tiger(animal: "my tiger"))` which makes use of the initialiser defined in `Animal` and you can replace "my tiger" with any name you want for your animal.

You were missing the implementation of the `init` method in `Zoo`. Understandably, you would like to assign the `weeklyHot` argument to the `weekHot` variable of the class `Zoo`. This can be done by `self.weekHot = weeklyHot`.

You can test out that your "weekHot" animal in the newly declared Zoo is really a tiger by calling the eat() method: `zoo.weekHot.eat()`

The complete code would look like this

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

class Animal{
    let animal :String
    enum Gender{
        case male
        case female
        case undefined
    }
    init(animal : String) {
        self.animal = animal
    }
    func eat(){
        print("I eat everyyhing")
    }
}
class Elephant : Animal{
    override func eat() {
        print("I eat grass")
    }
}
class Tiger : Animal{
    override func eat() {
        print("I eat meat")
    }
}
class Horse : Animal{
    override func eat() {
        print("I eat grass, too")
    }
}

class Zoo {
    var weekHot : Animal
    init(weeklyHot : Animal){
        self.weekHot = weeklyHot
    }
}
let zoo = Zoo(weeklyHot:Tiger(animal: "my tiger"))
zoo.weekHot.eat()
```

And the stdout would be

```
I eat meat
```

You can read more on inheritance in Swift from [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html) development document.